# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Jersey and Jackson Issue

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jackson, javabeans

I'm trying to retrieve a json object from my web service and turn it to a java object. I found that i can use a `POJO class` with `JavaBean`to bind my objects.

Well I tried to use `Jackson`so i added it to my pom like this :

here's my `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>DisasterManagement</groupId>
<artifactId>DisasterManagement</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and my `web.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>DisaterManagement</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/disastermanagement/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And I found on the internet that I can bind them like so :
my web service is like this :

```
    @Path("/update")
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
public void updateAlert(String test)  { 

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    //JSON to POJO
    Alert alert;
    try {
        alert = mapper.readValue(new File(test), Alert.class);
        System.out.println(alert.getName());
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    //return Response.status(200).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").entity("out from update").build();
}
```

And my POJO class object is just for a test like this one :

```
package com.disastermanagement.restjersey;

//@XmlRootElement



public class Alert{
      private String name;
      private String phone;

      public Alert(){
      }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
  }
  public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
  }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [name=" + name + ", name=" + phone + " ]";
    }
}
```

And while compiling I found this Error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer`

I'm really new with this and I don't know where I missed it.

I tried some solutions on StackExchange but it becomes a real mess.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

After modifying my pom it works and no more errors

My pom is like that now :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>DisasterManagement</groupId>
<artifactId>DisasterManagement</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But when calling my web service I have this Exception :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: {
    "phone": "jhsfd",
    "name": "Jane Doe",
}
```

Actually I send my json object but I don't know how to recieve it !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `servlet` dependency in your `pom` xml

`<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Now it's those errors : `StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParseException` ... `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException` and `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException`

Comment: you need to google the `classname` and just find the correct `jar` to add it in your `pom`

Comment: Check the Update please, I think it's another problem but i'll accept your answer

Comment: Actually I found the error, I was missing to make the POJO mapping true in my web.xml